# Updating OpenGL mipmapped texture

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

There is something I fail to understand completely about texture update in OpenGL.Let's say I create OpenGL texture with mipmaps like this:

```
        ///.. tex gen and bind here .... ///

        glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,numMipMapLevels,GL_RGBA8,imageInfo.Width,imageInfo.Height);
        glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,Width,Height,GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
        glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

**Now the first question:**
Does it mean ,when I want to update this texture including all the mipmap level ,do I have to loop over each level and call glTexSubImage2D with appropriate mipmap dimension and image bytes?If the answer is YES , then I have:

**second question**:
How do I retrieve each mipmap dimension and data to pass into the texture?

Alternatively , can I just do the update :

```
 glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,0,0,Width,Height,GL_BGRA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,data);
```

And re-generate mipmaps immediately afterwards?

```
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Answer to the first question

Yes

#### Answer to the second question

Each mipmap level has exactly half the width and height of the mipmap level above it. So for mipmap level *n* the dimensions are *w·2<sup>-n</sup>* and *h·2<sup>-n</sup>* where *w* and *h* are the size of level 0.

It can be easily programmed by recalling that bit shifting (the `>>` and `<<` operators in C like languages) are power of 2 operators. So *`a << n` = a·2<sup>n</sup>* and *`a >> n` = a·2<sup>-n</sup>*

#### Answer to the third qiestion

Yes, but the quality of the minification filter used by the particular OpenGL implementation may not meet one's demands.

Comment: Ok , and the pixel data for each mipmap should be "trimmed" or offset too ?

Comment: @MichaelIV: If by trimming you mean *downsampled* then yes. However if you use mipmapping then the downsampling filter should be something significantly better than sparse box or linear sampling because you get that for free using GL_NEAREST or GL_LINEAR. For best visual quality you should downsample using a Lancosz (aka sinc) filter from the original signal.

Comment: @datenwolf do you have any screenshot comparing visual quality with or withohut sinc filter (using GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR in both cases). I just googled around without finding any screenshot